# Using Replace in an update command DB2

Tags: sql, replace, db2

I have a quick requirement in which i need to update the data in my db which is corrupted.
I have a few text columns where the text contains &nbsp and although we have fixed the issue in code I still need to correct the corrupted data in db.

I think I can do

```
UPDATE table_name 
   SET column_name=(
        SELECT REPLACE(colum_name, '&nbsp;', '') 
        FROM table_name 
        WHERE id=1234) 
 WHERE id=1234
```

but I will have to do it individually for each row. Is there a easier query which will check all rows in the particular column and remove the &nbsp tag?

Thanks for the help.

Comment: This select would return multiple rows and update would fail.

Comment: Even with the correlated subquery? `UPDATE table_name t1 SET t1.column_name=( SELECT REPLACE(t1.column_name, '&nbsp;', '') FROM table_name t1)`

Comment: DB2 error 811 THE RESULT OF AN EMBEDDED SELECT STATEMENT OR A SUBSELECT IN THE SET CLAUSE OF AN UPDATE STATEMENT IS A TABLE OF MORE THAN ONE ROW, OR THE RESULT OF A SUBQUERY OF A BASIC PREDICATE IS MORE THAN ONE VALUE

Answer (score 14):

I think other experts are overcomplicating the solution that really only requires a simple `UPDATE`:

```
UPDATE table_name SET column_name = REPLACE(column_name, '&nbsp;', '') 
  WHERE column_name LIKE '%&nbsp;%'
```

Comment: Agreed, although I'd probably put a search in the `WHERE` clause to make sure it _has_ the offending value.  Not to speed things up against an index (full table scan required here folks), just to cut down on the number of rows actually updated (and the number of potential problems that could be created).

Answer (score 1):

You can do it with a stored procedure or anonymous block

It should be something like this.

```
begin
 declare atend boolean default false;
 declare val char(32);
 declare newstring char(32);
 declare c cursor for
  select col from table;

 open c;
 fetch c into val;
 while (atend = false) do
  set newstring = replace(val, '&nbsp;', '');
  update table set col = newstring where current of c;
  fetch c into val;
 end while;
end@
```